# Finding longest atom length from facts. (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have facts which define four names.

```
name('Fooo Baar').
name('Bar Fo').
name('Far Boooo').
name('Example Example').
```

How can I iterate through these facts to find out the longest name. Here's my current progress, but I don't have any ideas what to do next.

```
longest_name(L):-
   name(Nimi),
   atom_length(Nimi, L),
   write(L),
   nl,
   fail.
```

Comment: You can use e.g. `setof/3` to collect and sort the lengths of the atoms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a declarative approach:

```
longest_name(L) :-
    name(N), atom_length(N, L),
    \+ (name(X), atom_length(X, Y), Y > L).
```

\+ [means](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%5C%2B%29/1) not, so it should be fairly readable...

Comment: An issue with this definition is that it may provide repeated solutions if there are multiple atoms with the same max length. Maybe add a cut at the end?